# Webpack + Express: How to serve static resources in /node_modules from the server

Tags: node.js, express, webpack

I am trying to use webpack to generated a bundle.js file for a node module. The bundle.js file will be used in the client browser.

Here is the problem, the project has some dependencies that use static files in the node_modules directory. For example, the path of one of the static file is

`/node_modules/node-pogo-signature/lib/proto/Signature.proto`

When I try to run the bundle.js file in the browser, I get this error

```
GET http://localhost:3000/proto/Signature.proto 404 (Not Found)
```

If I copy the the Signature.proto file into my /public folder, the bundle will then find it. However, manually copying static files from /node_modules to /public can be tedious and hard to maintain. 
Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myfile = require('./node_modules/node-pogo-signature/lib/proto/Signature.proto');
```

Then you may add it to a route, for example if you use express this is how you can display the content of the `package.json` file:

```
// create a new express server
            var express     = require('express'); // We use express as web server http://expressjs.com
            var app = express();
            // serve the files out of ./public as our main files
               app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
           // start server on the specified port and binding host
            app.listen(appEnv.port, '0.0.0.0', function() { 
            console.log("server started");
            });

// Shows content of package.json
var myfile = require('./package.json');

app.get('/showfile', function (req, res){
    if (debug) {
        console.log("showfile received a request");
    };
    res.send(myfile);
});
```

You just have to add /showfile at the end of the url , for example : `http://localhost:6006/showfile`

Comment: In that case, if I need to add, say 5 files, then I create 5 vars for their paths, and put res.send(myfile1), res.send(myfile2), res.send(myfile3), res.send(myfile4), res.send(myfile5) into the app.get callback function?

Comment: For the first part, yes you may load each file in a separate var.
Avoid adding multiple `res.send()` to a single route.
You can concatenate the files into one string and send like `res.send(concatenated)`
The best solution would be to define a separate path for each of the files, so you can use a different url ending to access each file.